# Cant get the value on Firebase, Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some problem about reading value in Firebase, income and expense don't change when I run the project, seem like it didn't get the value on Firebase but I don't know why?

```
private void getMoney()
{
    myRef.child("money").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child("income").exists()) {
                    income = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("income").getValue().toString());
                }
                if (dataSnapshot.child("expense").exists()) {
                    expense = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("expense").getValue().toString());
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    money = income - expense;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtTong= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTong);
    getMoney();
    txtTong.setText("Money: " + money);
    initView();
```

Answer (score 2):

First in your onDatachange method of (getMoney()), change this part:

```
            if (dataSnapshot.child("income").exists()) {
                income = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("income").getValue().toString());
            }
            if (dataSnapshot.child("expense").exists()) {
                expense = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("expense").getValue().toString());
            }
```

to this

```
            if (dataSnapshot.child("income").exists()) {
                income = dataSnapshot.child("income").getValue(Integer.class);
            }
            if (dataSnapshot.child("expense").exists()) {
                expense = dataSnapshot.child("expense").getValue(Integer.class);
            }
```

and change the location of this:

```
        money = income - expense;
```

and put it at the end of onDatachange, under these:

```
               if (dataSnapshot.child("income").exists()) {
            income = dataSnapshot.child("income").getValue(Integer.class);
        }
               if (dataSnapshot.child("expense").exists()) {
            expense = dataSnapshot.child("expense").getValue(Integer.class);
        }

        //here you add it
        money = income - expense;
```

**EDIT**

look the values are retrieved well no problem with that, the only problem is to show the value in a textview.

when you setTEXT() outside onDatachange() the text view doesn't know what is the value of (money) because money will have the correct value only when it is placed in onDatachange.

So everything has to do with money should be included in onDatachange

so you do this :

```
       myRef.child("money").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.child("income").exists()) {
                income = dataSnapshot.child("income").getValue(Integer.class);
            }
            if (dataSnapshot.child("expense").exists()) {
                expense = dataSnapshot.child("expense").getValue(Integer.class);
            }

       //here you set money
       money = income - expense;

       //and also here you set the text

       txtTong.setText("Money: " + money);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

**This happens because onDatachange is not guaranteed to be called before you set the value of money in textview**

Comment: Its still not work, but when I put setText into onDatachange, It work but I dont know why

Comment: {
  "money" : {
    "expense" : 111,
    "income" : 123
  }
}

Its simple, I have not added anything yet

Comment: private ViewPager viewPager;
    TextView txtTong;
    int income=0,expense=0,money;
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();

Comment: sorry about this, this is the first time I ask in Stackoverflow, I dont know how to edit it right

Comment: check EDIT to understand why you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Can you make some changes in your code to 
   if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("income")) {
          income = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("income").getValue());
   }
   if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("expense")) {
          expense = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("expense").getValue());
   }
```

instead of

```
   if (dataSnapshot.child("income").exists()) {
          income = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("income").getValue().toString());
   }
   if (dataSnapshot.child("expense").exists()) {
          expense = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("expense").getValue().toString());
   }
```

I think your condition is not getting true try above code.

Comment: thank you for your comment, i have fixed it, it's not change but i know where am i wrong